# Group PWA notifications on Android

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I'm using the WebPush c# assembly (v1.0.11) to send push notifications to my PWA.

My payload looks like this:

```
{
"notification":{
"title":"My Message",
"body":"Hello World, here is a message for you",
"data":{
"FromContactpersonId":"e3600a03-836e-4c01-42c7-08d879cb6c81"},
"badge":"assets/icons/badge72push.png"}
}
```

Now I want to group the notifications on android. If I set `tag` in the payload it will replace the last message, but I want them all to show, just stacked, like the e-mails in this example (compared to my own, which are not stacked):

[image]

I tried adding `android_group` but the messages do not get stacked at all.

How can I send them so they will be stacked on my android device?

Thanks, Sam